# Is it possible to have total no. of blocks taken by same files be different on two PCs?

Tags: ls, tar

I used

```
ls -l mysoftware/
```

on two different machines, each running ubuntu 12.04.

But the 'total' returned by this command is different on the two machines. On one machine it is printing 6, and on another machine it is printing 24. 
Although I can see same number of files listed.

Actually I copied compressed folder mysoftware.tar.bz2 from my pendrive to these machines and then untar using the following command:

```
sudo tar xvfj mysoftware.tar.bz2
```

After that I used `ls -l` as above.

Since I was not able to install some software on the machine where I'm getting 6, I suspect some files are missing.

The question is can the two 'total' be different on different machines?

Comment: I think you mean `blocks`.

Comment: Is the name of the file really `mysoftware.tar.gz2`? Do you mean it's `mysoftware.tar.bz2`? I'm tempted to close this, your Q is still very unclear. There isn't any difference in a compress tar file when unpacked on 1 machine vs. another.

Comment: the real name is linux-STMDISCO-1.12.1.tar.bz2.  I can clearly see the output on the two machine for the same commands are different. That is why asking

Comment: The `sudo` command doesn't make sense either. I think you meant `sudo tar jxvf mysoftware.tar.bz2`.

Comment: @sim yes you are right. But I am not able to understand after I untar, why 'total' is different ? In fact in every PC I have tried it shows 24, but only on one PC it is showing 6

Comment: Is this file accessible via the internet somewhere?

Comment: The directory where you're trying to unzip it might be out of diskspace to accommodate the uncompressed files. You can chck in the directory using this command `df -h .`.

Comment: It is accessible, but I cant post the link, as it is for buyer only

Comment: On the bad computer try this command: `tar jtvf mysoftware.tar.bz2`. That lists all the files then it's probably the diskspace issue.

Comment: @sim it lists 10000 of files and exits. So what do conclude from this?

Comment: That all the files are there and intact and you're likely confusing something else. Can you include the actual output from these `ls` command showing the differences? I'm guessing some output from there is what's mixing you up.

Answer (score 2):

The "total" at the top of an `ls -l` listing is the sum of the blocks used by all the items in that listing. You can get the block count for each individual item by adding the `-s` flag.

Things to note about the block counts and "total":

1. `ls` doesn't report block counts using the filesystem block size (which is typically 4096 bytes) but in units of 1024 or 512 bytes depending on the version (and flags and sometimes environment variables). That's why on most modern systems block counts reported by `ls` are always a multiple of 4.
2. The size of a directory is not a recursive sum of the sizes of the things contained in it.

   ```
    mkdir a
    mkdir a/b
    head -9999999999c /dev/urandom > a/b/foo
   ```

   What will `ls -l a` show? It'll show `b`, which is a directory. And what is the size of `b`? Pretty small, probably 4 blocks (1 actual filesystem block) A directory is not a tarball; it doesn't physically *contain* the files under it. It is only a list of filenames and inode numbers. So the listing for `a` only includes `b` which is small, and the "total" for that listing is also small. `ls -l a/b` will show `foo` which is big, and the "total" will be big.
3. Since total is the sum of displayed items, `ls` options that change what is displayed also change the total.

   ```
   mv a/b/foo a/b/.foo
   ls -l a/b
   ```

   Because `.foo` starts with a dot, it is not included in the directory listing anymore. So the "total" is now 0, for a directory with a huge file in it! Add the `-a` flag and `.foo` shows up and the "total" becomes big again. In fact, the "total" is bigger than the block count for `.foo` because it also includes the block counts for `.` (`a/b`) and `..` (`a`). The `-A` flag is nicer (omit `.` and `..` but include all other dotfiles).
4. Block counts are not completely predictable from file sizes because different filesystems have different block sizes (so a file containing 1 byte will be reported as occupying 1 block on a filesystem with 1024-byte blocks, and 4 blocks on a filesystem with 4096-byte blocks), and also because the count includes filesystem overhead (*indirect blocks* which are where it stores the main list of blocks), and because there are *sparse files* - a big chunk of zeros in a file can be (but will not *always* be) stored in an efficient manner that occupies no additional blocks.

Comment: +1 To get the list numbering to work out, you need to add an indent to beginning of each new line (i.e. paragraph) of the text in the block, and an extra few spaces to the code segment.  You can see the difference if you check via 'edit'.